# Make integer series in php

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to make a integer series e.g I have data

```
0 ,0 ,7 ,0 ,10, 25, 0, 0, 30, 0
```

and I want to make this series as :

```
5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,10, 25, 26, 27, 30, 31
```

Basically I want to fill all the zeros in a series.

Can anyone help me out to make a program or an algo to calculate this.

Thanks

Comment: Why is the first value set as 5? Do any initial zeroes have to be anchored to the first non-zero value?

Answer (score 6):

A problem that's crying out for an `array_map` with an anonymous function. :)

```
$data = [0, 0, 7, 0, 10, 25, 0, 0, 30, 0];

$prev = 0;
// Wherever we have a zero, if we've already seen a non-zero number, replace it
// with the previous number plus one.
$data = array_map(function($v) use(&$prev) {
    $v = ($v ?: ($prev ? ++$prev : 0)); $prev = $v; return $v; }, $data);
// To handle the zeros before the first non-zero number, reverse the array,
// replace any zeros with the previous number minus one, then reverse it again.
$data = array_reverse(array_map(function($v) use(&$prev) {
    $v = ($v ?: --$prev); $prev = $v; return $v; }, array_reverse($data)));

var_dump($data);
/**
array (size=10)
  0 => int 5
  1 => int 6
  2 => int 7
  3 => int 8
  4 => int 10
  5 => int 25
  6 => int 26
  7 => int 27
  8 => int 30
  9 => int 31
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

`explode()` your string. Walk through the array using `foreach`. When encountering a zero value replace it with `$array[$index-1]+1`.

Comment: Your approach does not handle the cases when the array is starting with zero(s).